# Uninstall .NET Core SDK older versions

Tags: windows-10, .net-framework

I've got many versions of .NET Core SDK installed in my Windows 10 PC. I'm wondering if older versions can be uninstalled:

[List of installed softwares](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyrRm.png)

I'm not sure how .NET Core versioning works and if I need specific version in my PC.

Comment: .NET Core versions are backwards compatible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer by Damian Edwards,
PM Manager for .NET app frameworks (ASP.NET, CoreFX, EF, etc.) at Microsoft
is [quote](https://twitter.com/DamianEdwards/status/1043939217145913344):

> Delete them all, then nuke the dotnet folder in program files, then install the latest version.

You may uninstall all old versions one by one, or use a PowerShell Script
to delete. The following script is from the article
[Scripts to remove old .NET Core SDKs](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ScriptsToRemoveOldNETCoreSDKs.aspx):

```
$app = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object { 
    $_.Name -match "Microsoft .NET Core SDK"
}

Write-Host $app.Name 
Write-Host $app.IdentifyingNumber
pushd $env:SYSTEMROOT\System32

$app.identifyingnumber |% { Start-Process msiexec -wait -ArgumentList "/x $_" }

popd
```

You might do the same with the Microsoft .NET Framework,
if you are going to delete the dotnet folder.

This script requires you to hit YES because of elevation, but you may run it
from an elevated PowerShell shell.

Take backups before starting.

Comment: For some reason this doesn't require me to hit "Yes".. it started running and I don't see anything. EDIT: i had to hit "Ctrl+C", weird..